# Error while getting JSONArray from JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I'm trying to get a JSONArray from JSONObject, but get "Can't create JSONArray" in LogCat.

The error appears here:

```
JSONArray array = response_object.getJSONArray("post");
```

Here is my code:

```
try {
    int id;
    String author;
    String authorUniqueId;
    String authorPhotoUrl;
    String message;
    String createTime;

    JSONObject response_object = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray array = response_object.getJSONArray("post");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

        id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
        author = jsonObject.getString("author");
        authorUniqueId = jsonObject.getString("author_unique_id");
        authorPhotoUrl = jsonObject.getString("author_photo_url");
        message = jsonObject.getString("message");
        createTime = jsonObject.getString("created_at");

        Log.e("NewsActivity", "Added:" + author);


        data.add(new NewsDataModel(id, author, authorUniqueId, authorPhotoUrl, message, createTime));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Can't create JSONArray");
}
```

And my JSON:

```
{"error":false}
{"post":[
    {
        "id":"6",
        "author":"NAME..."
        "author_unique_id":"ID...",
        "message":"MESSAGE...",
        "created_at":"TIME...",
        "author_photo_url":"URL..."
    },

    {
        "id":"5",
        "author":"NAME..."
        "author_unique_id":"ID...",
        "message":"MESSAGE...",
        "created_at":"TIME...",
        "author_photo_url":"URL..."
    },

    {
        "id":"4",
        "author":"TEXT..."
        "author_unique_id":"ID...",
        "message":"MESSAGE...",
        "created_at":"TIME...",
        "author_photo_url":"URL..."
    }
]}
```

Comment: Your **JSON** is invalid. Look, it starts with this `{"error":false}`; the closing curly brace is ending your `JSONObject` at 1 key.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG, Oh, I didn't notice that! Thank you very much!

Comment: also change this int id = jsonObject.getInt("id"); to Stirng  id = jsonObject.getString("id");

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG, but id is int.

Comment: @MrAwesome `id` is out of reach for the moment. Consider fixing your JSON first.